# HTML + CSS to PDF without losing the format

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, jspdf

I wanted to print html table to a pdf file using javascript. for that I am using jspdf lib. and i have created this example

```
$(document).on('click', '#pdfbutton', function(event) {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter'),
    source = $('#printit')[0],
    specialElementHandlers = {
      '#bypassme': function(element, renderer) {
        return true
      }
    }

  var margins = {
    top: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 20,
    width: 700
  };
  pdf.fromHTML(
    source // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
    , margins.left // x coord
    , margins.top // y coord
    , {
      'width': margins.width // max width of content on PDF
        ,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    },
    function(dispose) {
      pdf.save('Test.pdf');
    },
    margins
  )
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6hngty42/

Now when I print the pdf it is showing me the different format of the html table.

how can i preserve the html and css to pdf?

or

how can I format the table using jspdf?

or

Is there any other js library which can print pdf to html with css offline (I checked [cloudformatter](http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.APIDoc.Usage) but it works online)?

FYI: I have checked other example also but none of the solution is useful for me.

Comment: Server side script would do it easily. If you can, than try [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/), it is best. Documentation is [here](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt).

Comment: Better use tcpdf, will print html exactly like you format.

Comment: @skobaljic, yes I searched wkhtmltopdf but dont know how to pass a specific element to it.

Comment: @Just_Do_It php won't work in my case :(

Comment: Look at documentation, in PHP just do `exec( command )`... if you want to output PDF, just add PDF headers... easy.

Comment: I am facing the same issue - https://anjanesh.com/resume.html - bottom - download in PDF - I don't think the CSS is getting loaded at all.